# Predicate Problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have a managed object with the field of journalHeaderID.  I can see via NSLog that those items are properly being placed into Core Data.   To display the data I need to filter by what is relevant to the view.

So as I'm configuring my view of this data I have created an array of IDs that are relevant.  When I run the code, though, I get no results even though I know they are there.

I thought this predicate was the right one to use, but it's not working right and I am not sure why.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"journalHeaderID IN %@", idsToList];
```

Here's the array as it passees into the predicate, and I've tried it as both NSNumber and NSString.

```
<__NSArrayM 0xa01af70>(
  800555,
  800552,
  800685,
  803592,
  803593
)


NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest new];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"JournalHeader" inManagedObjectContext:[[BWCoreDataHelper sharedInstance] managedObjectContext]];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setFetchBatchSize:20];

if( idsToList.count > 0 ) {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"journalHeaderID IN %@", idsToList];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
}

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"headerCreateDate" ascending:NO];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[sort]];

NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResults = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:[[BWCoreDataHelper sharedInstance] managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

self.fetchedResultsController = fetchedResults;
self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
```

Comment: what results *are* you getting? Apple docs say: "Equivalent to an SQL IN operation, the left-hand side must appear in the collection specified by the right-hand side. For example, name IN { 'Ben', 'Melissa', 'Nick' }. The collection may be an array, a set, or a dictionary—in the case of a dictionary, its values are used."

Comment: The data type in the array must match the data model, are they numbers or strings?

Comment: You don't seem to be calling performFetch.

Answer (score 0):

From the lack of information on what results you are getting, or even if you get the delegate message, I have one suggestion.

Call `- (void)performFetch:(NSFetchRequest *)fetch` on the `NSFetchedResultsController` with your created fetch.

If you're already doing this, then it isn't obvious.